# Converting Pdf in Taml language to epub using calibre

Tags: conversion, calibre, epub

I have tried to convert a pdf in tamil language using calibre. The conversion took place but the fonts are not in tamil. Is it possible to convert pdf in Tamil language to convert to epub? or Is there any other software in ubuntu for this purpose?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and I solved it by including the fonts I needed in the epub version of the file. You can do this with Sigil, which is an epub editor. To see how to include custom fonts in your epub with Sigil see http://web.sigil.googlecode.com/git/files/OEBPS/Text/tutorial_embed_fonts.html. See also karel's very useful comment below.

Comment: This is a good answer, but you could make it better by adding some more information about how to extract the font information from the pdf document using FontForge from the Ubuntu Software Center. For a step-by-step explanation of how to extract font info from a pdf document with fontForge see this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3488042/how-can-i-extract-embedded-fonts-from-a-pdf-as-valid-font-files/3489099#3489099 . Another alternative to the FontForge application also in the Ubuntu Software Center that you could try is MuPDF.

Comment: @karel: Thank you for adding this information. In my case I already knew what font I needed, so I completely overlooked this part of the process.

Comment: Font inclusion (via `@font-face`) is the best you can do, but it needs to be noted that it is not supported by many e-book readers.